# Can't smooth shade an imported fbx asset

Tags: modeling

this is my first post here so sorry if I'm not doing this right.
I'm currently on my 3rd ever project in Blender. I'm modelling a low polygon scene.  I wanted a low poly character to be in it, so I modelled and rigged on in a separate file and exported the character and rig as an fbx

When I import it, everything works good enough, except for some reason I can't smooth shade the mesh of the character. The option is still there and works for everything else in the scene, but when I select my character and try it, nothing changes.

Any idea what's up? I'm using Blender 2.8 if that helps (yeh, I know it's not finished, I'm just trying to get used to the new interface and taking advantage of I Eevee).

Comment: try disabling "auto smooth" in the object settings, if it's not disabled already

Comment: Try W -> Remove Doubles. I tell this literally everyone who has strange Problem with imported models. Most of the time it fixes most issues. After you did that try Ctrl + N to recalculate Normals

Comment: Thanks so much, both of you! I wound up recalculating normals and then changed the object settings and it worked! Cheers!